# I am Exporting a Html table in pdf with jspdf but hindi font font are note showing properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

```
  function generate() {

var doc = new jsPDF('1', 'pt', [842 ,595]);
   var htmlstring = '';

// Get the table element
const table = document.getElementById("student_table");

// Convert the table to PDF using autotable plugin


  doc.autoTable({
    html: table,
    startY: 20, // The position where the table should start in the PDF
    theme: "grid", // Other themes: 'striped', 'grid', 'plain', 'css'
    styles: {
    fontSize: 9,
    cellPadding: 3,
    lineWidth: 1,
    lineColor: [0, 0, 0],
    textColor: [0, 0, 0],
    overflow: 'linebreak',
        cellWidth: 'auto'
      },
      pageBreak: 'always',
      columnStyles: {
            0: { columnWidth: 'wrap' },
      }
    });
    

// Save the PDF with a filename
doc.save("table_to_pdf.pdf");

};
```

I am Exporting a Html table in pdf with jspdf but hindi font font are note showing properly
i want to show hindi properly how can i do this
Can I use Hindi font file.ttf
Or any other method to do this

[image]
[image]